# RXJS forkJoin also takes Observable<[]>?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have an array of numbers which I transform each number to an observable (which emits at random time)

When all observable are resolved , I display the result.

It's like `promise.all` so I'm using `forkJoin`.

```
let arr: Array<Number> = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let d = from(arr).pipe(mergeMap(f => myPromise(f)), toArray());
const example = forkJoin(d);
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

This does work as expected and I do see the overall results after random (max) time.

However , re-reading the docs , this ^ should not have worked.

[image]

Notice that `d` is type `Observable <{}[]>` so it's an Observable of array.

[*However the docs says*](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-forkJoin) :

> sources   :SubscribableOrPromise        Any number of Observables provided
>   **either as an array or as an arguments passed directly to the operator**.

But here  I don't pass an array. ( meaning , this : `forkJoin(...d)`  won't work).

**Question:**

Am I using the forkJoin incorrectly ? and how is it settled with the docs ?

[**OnlineDemo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-evaa9e?file=index.ts)

Comment: You are passing an Observable of array to the forkJoin, right? (d is an Observable of array)

Comment: @siva636 I'm passing an observable of array - as you see in the image. But the docs doesnt say that it takes observable of array. they say it takes an array(!) or single seperated items aka a,b,c,d

Comment: Doc says 'Any number of OBSERVABLES provided either as an ARRAY...'. This means array of Observables according to my understanding.

Comment: @siva636 Right. But in my example there is no array of Observables but **Observable of array**. `d` is `Observable<[]>` as you can see in the image

Comment: d is an Observable of array, but that array contains Observables?

Comment: @siva636 Do you understand that  `[Observable,Observable,]`  is not like `Obervable<[]>` ? According to the docs only the former should've been accepted. Also the samples [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) shows what I mean , that it takes array . not Observable of array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, "seems" like it works thanks to `mergeMap` and `toArray` but if you look at the output it's probably not what you wanted. It emits the resulting array inside another array while it looks like you wanted to get just an array of results.

This is what you get right now:

[image]

```
[
  [ "Promise Resolved: 1", "Promise Resolved: 2", "Promise Resolved: 3", "Promise Resolved: 4", "Promise Resolved: 5" ],
]
```

What's going on here is that you used `mergeMap` to project each number into a Promise and then `toArray` to collect all results and only after that the chain completes (it emits the resulting array as a single emission). Then `forkJoin` in fact doesn't subscribe to each individual Promise but only to the resulting Observable after `toArray` which is fine.

The documentation is correct because it allows multiple use cases such as:

```
forkJoin(a, b, c); // Observables as arguments passed directly to the operator
```

or

```
forkJoin([a, b, c]); // Observables as an array
```

Comment: OK , so how can I change the code to emit 0 nested array like you described ? ( Which is what i'm really after btw)

Comment: @RoyiNamir I was just getting ready to post something along the lines of this. As a reference, here are the lines in the `toArray()` source that show how it is gathering the results: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/perf/operators/toarray.js#L8-L21

Comment: You don't need to be using `forkJoin` at all because `toArray` does what you want already. https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-umq5x2?file=index.ts

Comment: I wanted to use it as promise.all

Comment: (learning purpose , say I give up on toArray) how can I use forkJoin with `...x` ?

Comment: [Found it `forkJoin(arr.map(f=> myPromise(f)));`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-evaa9e?file=index.ts)